# Opening a lightbox gallery without duplicating the first image?

Tags: image, wordpress, lightbox, colorbox, lightbox2

I'm using [Lightbox Plus](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/lightbox-plus/) (Colorbox-based) to create product galleries using NextGEN Gallery in WordPress (Don't worry -- this is more a programming question than a WP question; ergo why it's here).

Each product has a number of thumbnails linking to the full-sized image, grouped by rel. When I click any of the thumbnails, it opens as a grouped lightbox gallery; fantastic.

The problem I now face is that I'm needing to open each lightbox gallery from a text link. If I link to the first image in the set, the lightbox script interprets that as meaning I want that image twice in the set; not just invoke that particular lightbox group.

**How does one open a certain lightbox group without explicitly linking to an image?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the last entry in the ColorBox FAQ ("Create a separate link for opening a gallery"): http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/#click

Comment: That's what I'm looking for; I should have read the FAQ more extensively. Thanks!